# Обратиться к с элементам списка, вложенного в словарь Phyton

Tags: python, list, словари

Недавно начал изучать Python. Вот мне необходимо написать программу, которая на ввод будет получать данные, и если эти данные совпадают с ключом в словаре, то программа вернет значение по введенному ключу. Но в словаре есть ключи, у которых в качестве значения список.
Предположим пользователь вводит "numbers", но ему не нужен весь список, а нужен только его второй элемент, например. Не могу пока допереть как это лучше реализовать. Пока только мне подсказали как перебрать словарь, чтобы значения выводились красиво, а не в одну строчку. Это все что у меня есть:

```
`a = input("Введите данные: ")

 simple_dict = {"numbers" : ["here the number", "and here"], "numbers2" : ["1", "2", "3"]}

 def all_shift():
     i = 0
     while i < len(simple_dict[a]):
         print(simple_dict[a][i])
         i = i + 1`
```

Comment: а что мешает по ключу `numbers` обратиться сразу ко 2 элементу? Опишите более точно проблему или пример такого словаря

Comment: `simple_dict["numbers"][1]` - непонятно в чем у вас проблема

Comment: Если так обращаться, то значения вернутся в одну строчку (когда текс большой, то это выглядит ущербно, стих например). По-другому спрошу. Есть словарь со стихами, у каждого стиха в качестве ключа его название. Сам стих представляет собой список, в котором через запятую перечисляются строфы (с переносом строк, красиво, как в книжке). Мне нужно обратиться к словарю чтобы он нашёл конкретный стих и конкретную строфу и чтобы не в одну строчку. Вот.